# Mongoose: TypeError - Views.updateOne is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm encountering an issue with my Mongoose model when trying to use the updateOne method. I've defined a Mongoose schema called viewSchema, and I'm trying to update a document using Views.updateOne. However, I'm receiving a TypeError stating that Views.updateOne is not a function.

Reproducible Example:

```
const Views = require('../models/views');

//function update to add +1 to the number of views fro this day
  const updateViews = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Get today's date
      const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
      // Get tomorrow's date
      const tomorrow = new Date(today);
      tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  
      // Update the views for today
      const result = await Views.updateOne(
        { createdAt: { $gte: today, $lt: tomorrow } }, // Find document with today's date
        { $inc: { numberOfViews: 1 } }, // Increment the numberOfViews field by 1
        { upsert: true } // Create the document if it doesn't exist
      );
  
      // Send response
      res.json({ message: "Views updated", result });
    } catch (error) {
      // If an error occurs, send an error response
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  };
```

I expect the updateViews function to successfully update the document with today's date and increment the numberOfViews field by 1.

Comment: Post the contents of your `models/views` file. It needs to export an instance of a mongoose Model.

Comment: I realized that the issue was caused by using createdAt instead of created_at. Thank you for pointing that out!